# I am trying to set up a drupal site using docker in a Vagrant VM and can't seem to get Certbot to work

Tags: nginx, docker, vagrant, docker-compose, certbot

So I am trying to set up a drupal site using docker in a vagrant VM using bento/ubuntu-20.04.

I went through this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-drupal-with-docker-compose .  It seemed to work (I could navigate to the url I was using http 80 before I tried to set up https) but trying to implement the certbot setup it didn’t work.  I don’t think it is the certbot directly because when I do: `docker-compose exec webserver ls -lsh /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.otherrealm.org` there seems to be a valid certificate.  However, when I try to view the site using https/443, it does not work (gives ‘`The connection has timed out`’).  I can’t see anything wrong with my configuration but I’ve been staring at it for the past day and I need someone else to take a fresh look at it.  THANKS!!  Let me know if there is anything that is not clear.

**nginx-conf/nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name server.otherrealm.org;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name server.otherrealm.org;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.otherrealm.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.otherrealm.org/privkey.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    rewrite ^/core/authorize.php/core/authorize.php(.*)$ /core/authorize.php$1;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass drupal:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal
  drupal:
    image: drupal:fpm-alpine
    container_name: drupal
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - internal
      - external
    volumes:
      - drupal-data:/var/www/html
  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    depends_on:
      - drupal
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - drupal-data:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - external
  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/dns-google
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - drupal-data:/var/www/html
    command: certonly -d [sub.example.com] --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email [someone@example.com] --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal 

networks:
  external:
    driver: bridge
  internal:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  drupal-data:
  db-data:
  certbot-etc:
```

**vagrant@manager:/vagrant$ docker-compose ps**

```
 Name                 Command               State                     Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
certbot     certbot certonly --webroot ...   Exit 0
drupal      docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up       9000/tcp
mysql       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
webserver   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

**vagrant@manager:/vagrant$ docker-compose logs certbot**
(Of course, now it is saying `...too many certificates already issued for exact set of domains...` but that is because I tried it too many times ‍♂️)

```
Attaching to certbot
certbot      | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
certbot      | Renewing an existing certificate
certbot      | IMPORTANT NOTES:
certbot      |  - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
certbot      |    /etc/letsencrypt/live/[server.example.com]/fullchain.pem
certbot      |    Your key file has been saved at:
certbot      |    /etc/letsencrypt/live/[server.example.com]/privkey.pem
certbot      |    Your cert will expire on 2021-01-24. To obtain a new or tweaked
certbot      |    version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot
certbot      |    again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
certbot      |    "certbot renew"
certbot      |  - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:
certbot      |
certbot      |    Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
certbot      |    Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
certbot      |
certbot      | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
certbot      | Renewing an existing certificate
certbot      | IMPORTANT NOTES:
certbot      |  - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
certbot      |    /etc/letsencrypt/live/[server.example.com]/fullchain.pem
certbot      |    Your key file has been saved at:
certbot      |    /etc/letsencrypt/live/[server.example.com]/privkey.pem
certbot      |    Your cert will expire on 2021-01-24. To obtain a new or tweaked
certbot      |    version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot
certbot      |    again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
certbot      |    "certbot renew"
certbot      |  - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:
certbot      |
certbot      |    Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
certbot      |    Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
certbot      |
```

**vagrant@manager:/vagrant$ docker-compose logs webserver**

```
Attaching to webserver
webserver    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform 
configuration
webserver    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
webserver    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
webserver    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: error: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
webserver    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh  
webserver    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
webserver    | 10.0.2.2 - - [26/Oct/2020:23:16:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 169 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)" "-"
```

Comment: Are you sure port 443 is open and correctly forwarded?

Comment: You should not `--force-renewal` in your certbot command. That is why you got the error about too many renewals. And besides, that has nothing to do with the problem anyway. Certbot is working fine. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: -Will: ‍♂️ I think that is it.  Here I was racking my brains with something being wrong with my docker setup.Thanks! (and that is the downside to working remotely - I am sure if I was still working in an office with other developers around,I would have had this solved many hours ago)

Comment: Are you sure port 443 is open and correctly forwarded?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then, hopefully that solves it.